# Conditional Formatting with date comparison

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, json-formatting, conditional, classic-experience

I am using SharePoint 2016 on Premise in the classic mode.

I have a Custom List, and I want to apply conditional formatting to a date column, so that if the date is overdue from today's date it will display red and so on.

I've tried a few different JSON scripts, however they don't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using SharePoint 2016 classic experience, you can use Client Side Rendering (CSR) AKA JSLink which represents a rendering engine for list views, list forms and search results.

Below is sample code for your reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() { 
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
        OnPostRender: function (ctx) {
            // get today's date
            var today = new Date();
            // zero out the time portion so we will only compare days
            today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
            var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                // get the date set in your date YourDateField
                var itemDate = new Date(rows[i]['ContractExpirationDate']);
                // zero out the time portion so we only compare days
                itemDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
                var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
                var row = document.getElementById(rowId);
                if (row!=null&&itemDate <= today) {                  
                    row.style.backgroundColor = '#FF0000';                  
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

For more information, check below references:

1. [How to color code a SharePoint list date field based on comparison with todays date?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/252371/how-to-color-code-a-sharepoint-list-date-field-based-on-comparison-with-todays-d/252380#252380)
2. [How to highlight the row in red if expiration date is passed for SharePoint 2013 list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/254354/how-to-highlight-the-row-in-red-if-expiration-date-is-passed-for-sharepoint-2013)

Comment: Hi @Daryl, Did you try this solution? Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.