# In List Edit Mode Change List Item Color change based on custom column value

Tags: 2016

I have Custom List and I created some custom columns
In List Edit Mode  based on one Custom Column  value change to Yes( this type is Yes/No) i wan to change the Row color to Green.
Here how i do this from SharePoint Designer or any script i should write?

[image]

Comment: As you are using SP 2016, you may achieve this using client side rendering (CSR) / JSLink. For a start, check my answers given at [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/251405/how-to-highlight-a-row-on-active-status/251416), [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/252371/how-to-color-code-a-sharepoint-list-date-field-based-on-comparison-with-todays-d/252380#252380) & [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/292349/conditional-formatting-with-date-comparison/292351#292351).

Comment: Hi please can you send script that i have one custom column for example check out & its value (yes/no) , how to create the script for these .

Comment: When i try this script in your answer here https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/251405/how-to-highlight-a-row-on-active-status/251416 I got below error TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of nullTypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of nullTypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of nullTypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of nullTypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of nullTypeError: Cannot read property '_events' of null