# Jquery Encryption for SharePoint list view for all the fields in Email column, where as it is getting applied for one row in Title column as well

Tags: sharepoint-server, jquery

I'm using a below script in SharePoint all items aspx for Encrypting email column values, where it is also getting applied to one row in Title column. how to achieve this by not to encrypt the first field of title and to apply only for email column values.

```
<script src="../Script_Files/crypto-js.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var UpdateEmailColumnIndex = -1;
        var encryptedValueColumnIndex = -1;
        $("thead th").each(function (index) {
            if ($(this).text().trim() === "Email") {
                UpdateEmailColumnIndex = index;
            }
            if ($(this).text().trim() === "EncryptedFieldValue") {
                encryptedValueColumnIndex = index;
            }
        });
        if (UpdateEmailColumnIndex !== 1 && encryptedValueColumnIndex !== 1) {
            $("tbody tr").each(function () {
                var $row = $(this);
    
                var currentValue = $row.find("td:eq(" + UpdateEmailColumnIndex + ")").text();
    
                if (currentValue !== '*******') {
                    console.log("currentValue=" + currentValue);
                    const encryptedData = encryptData(currentValue);
                    console.log("encrypted=" + encryptedData);
                    $row.find("td:eq(" + encryptedValueColumnIndex + ")").text(encryptedData);
                    $row.find("td:eq(" + UpdateEmailColumnIndex + ")").text('*******');
                }
            });
        }
    });
    function encryptData(data) {
        var encryptionKey = '***********************';
    
        var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, encryptionKey);
    
        return encrypted.toString();
    }
</script>
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Try changing `if (UpdateEmailColumnIndex !== 1 && encryptedValueColumnIndex !== 1)` to `if (UpdateEmailColumnIndex != -1 && encryptedValueColumnIndex != -1)`.

Comment: no that didn't help

Comment: Instead of doing this based on table index (which might change if you change the column order in list view), try using Client Side Rendering (CSR) / JSLink for display customization of column data in list view. Check examples [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/251405/how-to-highlight-a-row-on-active-status/251416) and [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/254354/how-to-highlight-the-row-in-red-if-expiration-date-is-passed-for-sharepoint-2013/254360#254360).