# Column Formatting Option not available

Tags: 2013, json, json-formatting, column-formatting

I can't see an option for format column where I can enter JSON codes.

[image]

Comment: I would like to format a column in SP 2013 using CSR not based on a condition. Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **cannot** use column formatting using JSON in **SharePoint 2013**.

Column formatting using JSON is available for **SharePoint Online, SharePoint Server 2019, and SharePoint Online Small Business** only.

**Reference**:

1. [Column Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/column-formatting-1f927342-2bed-4745-b727-ff8b7ff96b22).

**Alternative solution**:

You can use Client Side Rendering (CSR) to highlight rows based on choice columns:

**Reference**:

1. [How to Highlight a Row on Active Status](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/251405/how-to-highlight-a-row-on-active-status/251416)

Comment: Does this answers your question?

Comment: Thank you Ganesh. Is there any alternative for me to use?

Comment: Yes you can use Client Side Rendering (CSR) using JSLink. See my answer given in updated answer link.

Comment: Please upvote and accept the answer if it helped you.