# Simple task: How to recolor a list line?

Tags: javascript, jslink, client-side-rendering

I just started learning Sharepoint. I have a problem that I can’t solve.
There is a list. It is necessary that for a certain value in a particular column the display of a particular row changes - the background color.

How to hook a label to check a specific column and after it repaints the row?

I found the code. I don’t understand how to adapt it to my needs:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//mysite/SiteAssets/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $Text = $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('Завершена')"); 
        $Text.parent().css("background-color", "#acf0bd");
        $Text = $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('В процессе выполнения')");
        $Text.parent().css("background-color", "#eac117");
        $Text = $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('Не начата')");
        $Text.parent().css("background-color", "#c7c5bc");
        $Text = $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('Просрочена')");
        $Text.parent().css("background-color", "#c1374f");
    });
</script>
```

I almost forgot. I use the utility to insert the code CISAR. Maybe I am not adding it there.

Comment: It can be done easily using Client Side Rendering (CSR). Refer this link; this will help you - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views

Comment: Check my answer given [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/251405/how-to-highlight-a-row-on-active-status/251416), maybe that will help you.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: Thanks to everyone for responding. Your answers helped me in solving problems.

Answer (score 0):

For such scenario's you can use Client Side Rendering in SharePoint.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views

Comment: Do I understand correctly that this method works with a column of type "Resultant Choice" ?? because I tried with the type "Resulting selection" and "The choice" (the choice from the proposed).
Or is it somehow tuned?