# SP 2013: Highlight Row if Field Value is empty

Tags: 2013, list, jquery, jslink, client-side-rendering

I need a script to highlight rows in a SP 2013 List if one field is null/empty.

Any help is appreciated!

Field: [Date Funded]

Thanks-

Comment: You can use Client side rendering/JS Link to highlight row based on column value. Check my answer given [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/251405/how-to-highlight-a-row-on-active-status/251416).

Comment: Ganesh!  Thank you!
To check for a null or empty value, would I use: varDate = {' ': '#color', ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Client side rendering/JS Link to highlight row based on column value. Similar to my answer given [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/251405/how-to-highlight-a-row-on-active-status/251416).

Try something like below:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", 
"SPClientTemplates", function() {
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.
RegisterTemplateOverrides({
  OnPostRender: function(ctx) {
     var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
     for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
     {
         var dateFunded = rows[i]["DateFunded"]; // use internal name of your column here
         var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
         var row = document.getElementById(rowId); 
         if(!dateFunded) {
             row.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000"; //Red color
         } 
     }
   }
}); 
});
```

**Reference**:

[Find the internal name of SharePoint column](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Comment: Thank you again Ganesh.  This is perfect-
Have a good & safe day-