# Color Coded Columns in SharePoint 2013 classic view

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, javascript, jslink, client-side-rendering

I am trying to create a custom list that has custom color coding that is dependent on what the choice field values.

I have tried to save my JavaScript file to my site assets and master pages of the root site and then edit the view in a list web part and have the web part point to the JSLink that is provided, but it continuously does not work.

All it does is it will just get rid of the title column. The color will not appear. Is there a simple way to do this without having to point it to the JSlink?

Also, do I need to have the jQuery library uploaded to my site in order over the JavaScript to work. Any insight on how I could make a status tracker with color coded column I would greatly appreciate it.

I have feeling very defeated at the moment.

Comment: Can you edit your question here and post your code?  It would help us help you figure out what is going wrong if we can see the code.  Also, you are asking about jQuery - are you trying to use jQuery in your CSR code?

Comment: Not completely sure about what you are trying to achieve. But, see my answer & code given [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/251405/how-to-highlight-a-row-on-active-status/251416#251416) which might help you.