# SharePoint O365 Classic Library - Color Code Cell with no CEWP/Script Editor

Tags: column-formatting, classic-experience, color-field

First, I know if I use the Modern experience in my library in SP O365 this would resolve my conditional formatting issue.

However, if I can find a solution that does not require a CEWP/Script Editor, that avoids many other issues I have with the boundaries of the templates within the "modern" experience that MS has imposed.

I have a File Health column with the following drop downs: No Issues, Minor Issues, Major Issues.  I need to color code each of these to show green, dark yellow(gold), and red fonts accordingly.

I have access to use SP Designer 2013, however I am not sure that is helpful at this point.

Your help and time are GREATLY appreciated!~

Comment: Are you using classic experience or modern experience? Also, team site template or communication site?

Comment: Ganesh, I am using a Classic Experience and it is on a Team Site Template.

Comment: For modern experience, you can use [column formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting), for classic experience, you can use JSLink. Check my answer at (for example): https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/251405/how-to-highlight-a-row-on-active-status/251416#251416

Comment: Yes, I am aware, however my SharePoint O365 does not provide CEWP or Script Editor.  My IT Department does not want to enable that across our enterprise.

Comment: You don't need CEWP or script editor for this. You can provide jslink URL in list webpart settings.

Comment: Ganesh, I don't see the option under the Misc menu in my web part for my library.